# FB Page is subscribed to multiple webhooks

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I've got a FB page, that I used on a bot creation platform, then I use it for another bot creation platform.

What I expected was FB to cancel the previous subscription before setting the second one but looks like no.

I always get 2 responses, one from each of the platform.

I'm testing a handmade webhook, now and I'm getting 3 responses, the previous 2 ones and mine.

Is there a way to make FB drop the 2 first webhooks ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/

Comment: @CBroe from that doc, you can only unsubscribe your own app, you can't unsubscribe other apps subscriptions

Comment: Well then you will have to go back to the platforms were you did this in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

By going to your page Settings and then Messenger platform  you can uninstall any applications you do not wish to receive postbacks and/or send messages.

Answer (score -1):

I have done few things with the facebook. And one of the easiest is what you are asking for.

1. So go to https://developers.facebook.com
2. Log and find you app
3. Go to webhooks
4. There are listed all the webhooks and next to each of them there is a button "Unsubscribe"
   It is working without any verifications etc..

Comment: Well, I think you don't understand the question